# How to change the name of a query string key?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to know the best way to do the following url rewrite in apache?

```
http://foo.com/login?old_key=some_value
```

Redirect to:

```
http://bar.com/login?new_key=some_value
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate querystring in 2 ways on apache

using 
`%{QUERY_STRING}`
 variable

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^old_key=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/?login http://bar.com/login?new_key=%1 [NC,L,R]
```

using 
`%{THE_REQUEST}`
 variable

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /login/?\?old_key=([^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^/?login http://bar.com/login?new_key=%1 [NC,L,R]
```

Both examples above redirect the requested uri 
`/login?old_key=foobar`
 to the new host 
`http://bar.com/login?new_key=foobar` .